# Python - How to insert an element in the top of a dictionnary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I know there is no order in a Python's dictionary, but I have a JSON file which contains dictionaries, and I want to insert an element in every dictionary In a way that when I will open the JSON I will see the element added in the top.

Exemple: File JSON contains:

**{"b":2, "c":3}**

Should be like this after adding:

**{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}**

Comment: Each json should only describe one object.  You could replace the first opening bracket `{` with `{ "a": 1, `, or do the same for every opening bracket, depending on how you want to handle nested objects.

Comment: "An object is an _unordered_ set of name/value pairs.", says json.org. `{"a":1, "b": 2}` and `{"b:2", "a":1}` must be considered equal. If an implementation depends on order of keys in a dictionary, it is broken. If order is important, a list of pairs should be used. If you can fix the implementation, consider doing that. (If not, my condolences.)

Comment: @9000 you might want to stick an element at the top even if the implementation does not depend on the order of the keys.

Comment: @pvg: Could you please offer a rationale for that?

Comment: @9000 sure. You're modifying a human-readable config file. You care about order and where your modifications go. JSON is both an abstract data structure _and_ a text format. It's perfectly reasonable to want to exercise control over the text for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: @pvg: I see your point. JSON is a _very_ bad human-readable config file format. Lack of comments disqualifies it immediately, but a bunch of other issues exist. My condolences, as said above; unfortunately, it's still widely used as such.

Comment: It's a fix-first-argue-later type of situation.

Comment: @Coldspeed: Usually it's due to the "implement first, think later" approach, likely by entirely different people :( If there's a chance to replace it instead of band-aiding it, it's great; unfortunately it's usually "not right now".

Comment: @9000 beats xml. Plus, most things that use JSON for config just accept comments and it works fine - Crockford removed comments for completely different reasons. Check out the config of say, Sublime or VSCode.

Comment: @svg: Glad to hear that! Maybe one say this config-friendly-JSON will be formally standardized.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a little trick with `OrderedDict` to do this.

Step 1: Have your old data stored somewhere.

```
import json 
s = {"b":2, "c":3}
json.dump(s, open('file.json', 'w'))
```

The data looks like this: `'{"b": 2, "c": 3}'`

Step 2: When adding new data, use an `OrderedDict` to load your existing data.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

new_data = OrderedDict({'a' : 1})
new_data.update(json.loads(open('file.json'), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict))
json.dump(new_data, open('file.json', 'w'))
```

And now, the data looks like this: `'{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}'`

Comment: Why not just use the built-in `sorted()` function?

Comment: That returns tuples. You can't sort a builtin dict because it has no ordering.

Comment: You're changing the fundamental structure of the JSON.

Comment: Also this is about maintaining an insertion-based order not the natural order of they keys or values which in this case is incidental

Comment: @l'L'l: You undoubtedly wanted to use an `OrderedDict` in your example. The dict comprehension you offers returns an entirely different document.

Comment: @9000: Coldspeed already said essentially the same thing, and of course the example creates a new json dict. I read "added to top" as "add k,v to dict, sort and output json", but thanks anyway :)